# image display in block <a> - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page like below;

```
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#div2 a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF9900;
    height: 51px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
#div2 img {
    border:0;
    float: right;
}
</style>

<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <a href="">text1 text2 text3 text4  text5 text6 text7 text8<img src="image.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am getting is something like this;

[image: current]

and I want this;

[image: result]

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/erUxF/)** is the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to `#div2 a` and `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;` to `#div2 img`.

***[See working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/pAhvY/):***

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <a href="">text1 text2 text3 text4  text5 text6 text7 text8<img src="http://i.imgur.com/VlyB1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#div2 a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF9900;
    height: 51px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
#div2 img {
    border:0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

see fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfAdE/1/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bfAdE/1/embedded/result/

Note: As i dont have image so i just put the border red on img tag and set the width and height for demo.

SS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to position your elements instead of relying on floats.

Add the following:

```
#div2 a { position:relative}
#div2 img {position:absolute; top:0; right:0;}
```

Also remove the float from your img.

See the example here http://jsfiddle.net/brZdW/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#div2 a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF9900;
    height: 51px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
#div2 img {
    border:0;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VlyB1.jpg"><span>text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 text6 text7 text8</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: No you are not lagging you have just chosen another approach by setting a position for the image. But I personally don't like to use positions when it is not really necessary. Just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/erUxF/16/

By relative positioning the div2, you have the built in magic of absolutely positioning elements that are relative to div2, not the page, so you can use left, right, and top to put the img where you want it.